# Convert dates from ISO time format to yyyy/mm/dd.hh:mm:ss

Tags: regex, linux, csv

How do I convert this:

`2013-08-16T13:24:18+0200`

from the current format which is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+hhmm` to this format?

`yyyy/mm/dd.hh:mm:ss` (`2013/08/18.13:24:18`)

The values are in a csv file and there are also negative values so I can't just substitute hyphens with forward slashes, also I want the part that specifies the time zone removed.
My knowledge of sed and awk is very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting CSV can be very tricky depending on whether everything is quoted or nothing is quoted, or some fields are quoted.  And then, we can start worrying about whether there are escaped quotes inside your strings.  Or commas inside your strings.

Without knowing your data better (perhaps there are no commas in your strings and no quotes to worry about), you may or may not be able to use sed/awk.  If you have complex CSV, I suggest something with more kick like perl and Text::CSV.

So, I will show you how to parse a file of *Just dates* in order to leave the CSV complications out of this.

The perl way:

```
cat tmp.txt | perl -e 'for (<>){ s!(\d+)\D(\d+)\D(\d+)T(\d+)\D(\d+)\D(\d+)\+.*!$1/$2/$3.$4:$5:$6!; print $_}'
```

The SED way:

```
sed -r 's!([0-9]+)\D([0-9]+)\D([0-9]+)T([0-9]+)\D([0-9]+)\D([0-9]+)\+.*!\1/\2/\3.\4:\5:\6!' tmp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks good response seems I don't have enough points to upvote anything thanks for all the good responses. I'm going to start learning perl today seems very useful.

Comment: just in case, the same regex with a european date in return (dd/mm/yyyy) and only HH:mm without seconds: sed -r 's!([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+)!\3/\2/\1 \4:\5!' afile.txt